# Tag <p> doesn't keep the value received from a <script>

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

i'm testing a HTML using a  to check what a servlet returned, 
to choose which message i'll show. The app runs ok, the servlet returns correctly. The  get what the servlet returned and chooses the message. But, the tag  shows the message only for a second (like a flash) and erase shortly thereafter. Below you can see my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="pt-br">        
   <head>
      <title> loginServlet2 </title>
      <meta http-equiv = ”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8”>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c:/java/html/css/estilo.css"/>  

      <script>
         function oMsg()
         {
            var wMsg1 = document.getElementById('wMsg').innerHTML;
            if (wMsg1 == "Test OK!")
            {
               document.getElementById('wMsga').innerHTML="Test is OK";
            }
            else
            {
               document.getElementById('wMsga').innerHTML="Test is not OK";
            }
         }
      </script>                    
   </head>

   <body>
      <h2> Login Page2 </h2>

      <p>Please enter your username and password</p>

      <form method="GET" action="loginServlet2">
         <p> Username <input type="text" name="userName" size="50"> </p>

     <p> Password <input type="text" name="password" size="20"> </p>

     <p> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1" onclick="oMsg()"> </p>
      </form>

      <p id="wMsg"> Msg1 : <%=request.getAttribute("wMsg")%></p>
      <p id="wMsga"> Msg2 : </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Could you help me, please? Thanks.

Comment: It's because your javascript code runs, changing the content of wMsga, and then your form immediately submits reloading the whole page.  What to do next depends on whether or not you want that form to submit.

Comment: If i understood your probelm you need to call the JS method if the wMSG param is set right?

Comment: Hi Niton. What i want is show the Page with fields User, Password, wMsg1 and wMsg2 with blanks (spaces). When user clicks the Button i'll call Servlet and, after, call Function oMsg() and that function will select the correct message using a field received from Servlet (id="wMsga")  and put it (the correct message) into id="wMsga". The id="wMsg" will keep the original message received from  Servlet. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm answering what you are looking for, but adding return false to onclick will keep you on the same page:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1" onclick="oMsg(); return false;">
```

Comment: James, actually i wanna that app shows the page askying username and password. While the user doesn't click in the button, nothing has to happen. After the button was clicked, the servlet has to be called and return "Test OK". After that onclick has to call the <script> that will choose wich message will be sent. After send the message the page has to stop, keeping the message there. wpalmes, i've tryed what you sugest, but the problem still there.